# How to run python file after docker-compose in a shell script?

Tags: python, docker, shell

I want to run a python file after a `docker-compose` file, which contains localstack. This is how I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
python main.py
```

After running the docker-compose file, it does not proceed to run my next command. Can anyone help me to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` argument to `docker-compose up` will make it detach from the containers and return, so that other commands can run:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
python main.py
```

Just make sure your other command does not run too early if it relies on the containers.

Comment: How can I make the python file run after the container has been set up? Should I add sleep?